# the use of will find/have or would find/have are the same or they have different meanings in the below sentences?

Tags: will-would

I am trying to say traveling brings opportunities to develop different skills. Which one is correct? Traveling is good...
People would have/find the opportunity to develop ... 
People will have/find the opportunity to develop ..

Comment: Those mean different things.

Comment: that is the question, can you explain?

Answer (score -1):

*Ah, sadly both sentences are wrong.* **Neither 'would have' nor 'will have' suits the situation.**

*The correct alternative is:*

> Travelling is good. People get opportunities to develop.

or

> Travelling is good. People find opportunities to develop.

But for your query in regard to the difference between 'would have' and 'will have', here's a detailed explanation:

**We use 'will have' when we are 'looking back from a point in time in the future' or 'from the present':**

*For example:*

> I will call Steve at six. He will have reached home by then. (Looking
>   back from a point in time in the future)
>
> It's six o'clock. Steve will have reached home by now. (Looking back
>   from a point in time in the present)

**We use 'would have' as 'the past tense form of will have':**

*For example:*

> It's already seven. Steve would have reached home by six.

**We also use would have in conditionals to talk about something that did not happen in the past:**

*For example:*

> I would have been very angry if Steve had got late.

*Hope, it helped :)*

Comment: "get" is informal and may not be the right choice in all contexts, e.g. not in an academic essay.

Comment: 'Travelling is good' is informal too. I answered accordingly!!! And the word 'get' is a normal word. Where did you read about 'get' being informal?  :/

Comment: That shows how my question was misunderstood, I am sorry, I used "have" for possession : people will/would find(have) the opportunity, and I am looking for use of would in future for hypothesis purpose and comparing with will

Comment: You're confusing the main/lexical verb usage of 'have' –  'People will find the opportunity to develop'  / 'People will have the opportunity to develop'  (cf 'I will have/possess the complete set of cards when I get Messi') – with the auxiliary usage ('I will have reached home by 6 pm'). OP asks about whether 'would have / would find', or 'will have / will find', is better. / While I too prefer your rewrite, although 'get' is not at the most formal end of the spectrum (though Stuart's comment is probably too stark), 'People will have/find the opportunity to develop ...' is hardly _wrong_ here.